# Variable not reassigning on checked value

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Value of variable garageVal is not being updated on checkbox selection.

Since the default position of the checkbox is checked on the first selection, garageVal is 15000, but it does not change when a different value is selected.

The purpose of this section is to calculate an estimate on a house. garageVal is plugged into a calculator along with other variables to generate a final value.

HTML:

```
  <div class="garage-block">
      <input type="checkbox" class='g1' name='garage'/>1</label>
      <input type="checkbox" class='g2' name='garage'/>2</label>
      <input type="checkbox" class='g3' name='garage'/>3</label>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
    let g1 = document.querySelector('.g1');
    let g2 = document.querySelector('.g2');
    let g3 = document.querySelector('.g3');
    let garageVal;
    if(g1.checked = true){
       garageVal = 15000;
    }else if(g2.checked = true){
       garageVal = 30000;
    } else if(g3.checked = true){
       garageVal = 45000;
    }
    console.log(garageVal);
```

console will show 15000 by default, despite my efforts, I have not been able to update garageVal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if and elseif statements run immediately when the script is loaded.  So on page load, the script runs, evaluates which boxes are checked, and then assigns a value based on your HTML.  You need to add eventlisteners to each checkbox to have them update live.  For example:

```
g2.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // if statement to see if box is already checked or not
    if (g2.checked === false){
        g2.checked = true;
        garageVal = 30000;
    } else {
        g2.checked = false;
        // remove 3000 from garageVal, or whatever you need done when box is unchecked
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: adding the event listener fixed it, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (g1.checked = true)
```

Your conditions are all assignments, which is always `true`, especially at the first check (assignments are expressions which evaluate to the value assigned).

```js
const obj = {}
const foo = (obj.rar = 'yasss!') // "=" is assignment, not comparison
console.log('obj.rar:', obj.rar) // 'yasss!', but you probably didn't expect this
console.log('foo:', foo)         // also 'yasss!', but you probably expected boolean
```

Change `=` to `===` to make it a comparison:

```
if(g1.checked === true){
   garageVal = 15000;
}else if(g2.checked === true){
   garageVal = 30000;
} else if(g3.checked === true){
   garageVal = 45000;
}
```

or just omit the comparison since `element.checked` is a boolean value already.

```
if(g1.checked){
   garageVal = 15000;
}else if(g2.checked){
   garageVal = 30000;
} else if(g3.checked){
   garageVal = 45000;
}
```

Comment: strangely enough this assignment operator is the only thing that is working (both == and === did not do anything). This was my initial thought as well. g1.checked...etc. also does not work. Assignment operator is the only thing that has worked at all (albeit not working properly) out of everything I have tried